# Postgresql won't restore dump

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, pg-restore

I've been trying to restore dump file dump-postgres-202010121008.sql but it won't be restored, I've tried the following restoration methods but it seems of no use:

**Method1: using pgAdmin 4**

I've tried the pg_restore method with the following inputs:

Format: custom or tar

File name: path to the file

Number of jobs: empty

Role name: postgres

When i click restore, i get a `Failed(exit code: 1)` with the following error message:

```
pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive
```

I've also tried Query Tool > open file, still i got an error `File type not supported`.

**Method 2: using command line**

I've tried pg_restore command on terminal but it returned `pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive`

I've also tried the following commands:

```
su postgres
psql postgres
\i dump-postgres-202010121008.sql
```

However i got this log:

```
psql:dump-postgres-202010121008:42473: error: invalid command \��0�8�ӛӣ��X�H6����.�y�:���e�ne��Pc�9x@%"˔U�rV7M=�
psql:dump-postgres-202010121008.sql:42474: error: invalid command \�T����kW:����Һ�-kL
psql:dump-postgres-202010121008.sql:42484: error: invalid command \M�Ǉ,�ϐ}�c,J�-�)ATo▒�HJ��+w
psql:dump-postgres-202010121008.sql:783003: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xea 0xab 0x7a
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What command generated the dump?

Comment: hello, i've been given this dump to test an application, so i have no idea what is the command, do i need the command that generated this dumb to restore it ?

Comment: update: the dump file is generated by dbeaver

Comment: The problem is still the same, DBeaver allow you to chose between `pg_dump` and `pg_dumpall`. You can also change any parameter. You problem seems to be related to custom mode and encoding. But it is impossible to tell without having the dump file. I strongly suggest you to get information about the dump format to properly reverse and restore. Always remember a backup is complete when it is proven that it can be restored. Dumping a file is just the first step of a backup.

Comment: Hello @jlandercy , thank you for your response.
As you said, the problem was with the encoding of the dump file. When dumping, you have to configure your dump file encoding so it responds to your database encoding.
In my case, the file's encoding and the database's encoding were different, that's why when selecting the database and restoring the dump file, it threw an error.

Comment: Glad you found it. Have a good day